# <PHP> How to make echo stay on the page permanently with sessions?

Tags: php

I have code, which is supposed to echo if it's true.
I did this with an if, but every time I run the code it will replace the previously echo'd number.
Can I make it so echo doesn't replace the past echo, but add an additional $i every time I run the code?

```
$i = $_SESSION["priem"]; 
$i++;
$aantaldelers = 2;

for ($j = 2; $j < $i; $j++) {
      if ($i%$j == 0) {
         $aantaldelers++;
      }
}

if ($aantaldelers == 2) {
    echo "$i, ";
}

$aantaldelers = 2;
$_SESSION["priem"] =  $i;
```

Comment: is this the full code?

Comment: Is this because the browser clears the page every time you run the code? If so, you could have another session var that you concatenate the count to, and display that instead.

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? If you change your variables from call to call, this looks pretty usual to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can do it by adding a string in session same as variable

```
$i = $_SESSION["priem"]; 
$i++;
$str = isset($_SESSION["str"]) ? $_SESSION["str"] : '';  //my changes
$aantaldelers = 2;
for ($j=2; $j<$i; $j++)
   if ($i%$j == 0)
       $aantaldelers++;
if ($aantaldelers == 2) {
   $str .= "$i, "; //my changes
   echo $str;      //my changes
}
$aantaldelers = 2;
$_SESSION["priem"] =  $i;
$_SESSION["str"] =  $str; //my changes
```