# How can I make an echo on php stay on page forever

Tags: php

I am experimenting with a code for a social media feed. My problem here is that when i press the post button to add a new post, it replaces the previous one. I searched on google to find an answer and I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60075529/php-how-to-make-echo-stay-on-the-page-permanently-with-sessions?answertab=votes#tab-top).

However I don't completely understand how it can be used in my situation. So how can I make this work? Here is my code:

```
    <?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $post = $_POST['post'];
    echo "<div class='post'>" . $post . "</div>";
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Feed</title>
    <style>
        body {
            background-color : white;
        }

        .post {
            position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 4px solid black;
  padding: 50px;
  margin: 20px;
}

    .textarea {
        position: absolute;
  left: 600px;
    }

    .button {
        position: absolute;
  left: 900px;
  top: 50px;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="post">
    <textarea class="textarea" cols="30" rows="5" name="post"></textarea>
    <input class="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Post" id="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Forever? That's not possible, since the user can always clear their cache, cookies, and local storage. But you can store them semi-permanently on the server side as others have already answered. You can even use Javascript to add posts to the DOM, and store them in `localStorage` if you don't want to store them on the server.

Comment: George, I would say you have to either save your post in a database. And then on page refresh you can fetch the data from the table to show it. Or else it wont stay forever.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like that, but it wouldn't be permanent, if you want to make it permanent, you need to use some kind of db.

```
<?php

session_name('YOUR_SESSION');
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['posts']))
{
    $_SESSION['posts'] = array();
}

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{
    array_push($_SESSION['posts'], $_POST['submit']);
}

foreach ($_SESSION['posts'] as $post_temp) 
{
    echo "<div class='post'>" . $post_temp. "</div>";
}

?>
```

Also, you need to edit css, cause you are printing post under each other